# Passing any class member function as parameter

Tags: c++, member-functions

i'm trying to pass a class member function as a parameters
this work perfectly when i'm using the folowing code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

class CMother;
typedef int(CMother::*FuncPtr)(char* msg);

class CMother
{
protected:
    void SetFunctionPtr(FuncPtr ptr)
    {
        //get ptr here
    }
};

class CSon : public CMother
{
public:
    CSon()
    {
        SetFunctionPtr((FuncPtr)MyFunc);
    }
private:
    int MyFunc(char* msg)
    {
        printf(msg);
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CSon son;
    return 0;
}
```

but when i try to generalize the `typedef` section with a template i'm getting a `fatal error C1001: INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR`
the complete code that generate this error is

```c
#include <stdio.h>

template<class T>
typedef int(T::*FuncPtr)(char* msg);

class CMother
{
protected:
    void SetFunctionPtr(FuncPtr ptr)
    {
        //get ptr here
    }
};

class CSon : public CMother
{
public:
    CSon()
    {
        SetFunctionPtr(MyFunc);
    }
private:
    int MyFunc(char* msg)
    {
        printf(msg);
        return 0;
    }
};

void mmm()
{
    CSon son;
}
```

can any one help me with this please.

Comment: I know this is not what you are asking, but why can't you use a virtual function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ have no template typedefs until C++11.